# Assign split string to parsed int

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, parseint

i'm getting this error and i can't quite figure out how to fix it.

> error:
>      
>  incompatible types
>   
> found   : int
>   
> required: int[]
>
> array[x] = Integer.parseInt(elements[0]);

here is the code for my method. The file being used is a text file of 1000 numbers, 2 per line with 500 lines, separated by commas.

Example:

1,2

16,92

109,7

the purpose of this block is to read all lines of the text file, and assign all numbers to the 2d integer array.

```
public static int[][] writeTypes(){
    String position;
    String[] elements = new String[2];
    int x;
    int y=1;
    int array[][] = new int[500][2];
    File TypesFile = new File("Types.txt");

    try {
        Scanner twoput = new Scanner(pkTypesFile);
        for(x = 0; twoput.hasNext(); x++){
            position = twoput.nextLine();
            elements = position.split(",", 2);

            array[x] = Integer.parseInt(elements[0]); 
            array[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(elements[1]);

            System.out.println(array[x] + " " + array[x][y]);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.format("Types File does not exist.\n");
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: array is a 2 dimensionnal array. When you do `array[x] = Integer.parseInt(elements[0]);` it's like doing `int [] someArr = anInt`, which is invalid (because `Integer.parseInt` returns an integer).

Comment: @ZouZou you should give that as answer

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about indexing into multidimensional arrays.  `array` is a 2-dimensional array, meaning it's an array of arrays.  `new int[500][2]` creates an array of length 500, each element of which is an `int[]` of length 2, each element of which is an int.  The expression `array[x]` selects one of the 500 `int[]` arrays of length 2.  The compile error is saying you can't assign an int to an `int[]`.  You need to provide another index to select one of the ints in the array denoted by `array[x]`.

Specifically, you should change

```
array[x] = Integer.parseInt(elements[0]); 
array[x][y] = Integer.parseInt(elements[1]);
System.out.println(array[x] + " " + array[x][y]);
```

to

```
array[x][0] = Integer.parseInt(elements[0]); 
array[x][1] = Integer.parseInt(elements[1]);
System.out.println(array[x][0] + " " + array[x][1]);
```

The second index selects one of the ints in the `int[]`, which you can then assign to.